# Добавить блок в виджет сайдбар в шаблоне WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

В шаблоне WP подключен сайдбар через `register_sidebar`в файле functions.php.

В тот же сайдбар необходимо добавить еще один блок с текстом и ссылками такого вида:

```
<div id="block-goods">
<h2 class="block-goods-title">
    <a href="http://link/">Title</a>
</h2>
<div class="block-goods-list">
    <div>text</div>        
    <a class="block-goods-img-link" href="http://link/"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Знаю как статично добавить этот блок в админке в разделе "Виджеты".

Как добавить этот блок с возможностью редактирования текста? И как правильно подключить ссылку на внутренние страницы сайта в этом блоке?

**UPD**

На сайте уже подключен (зарегистрирован) сайдбар. Мне надо в него добавить новый блок с текстом и ссылками. И еще необходимо чтобы этот блок выводился только на главной странице.

Предыдущий сайдбар создан в sidebar.php:

```
<div id="right-column">
     <?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar1') ) : ?>
      <?php endif; ?></div>
```

и подключен в index.php так:

```
<div class="sidebar" id="sideRight">
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Не совсем догоняю, что вы хотите сделать. У вас есть зарегистрированный сайдбар, соответсвенно у него есть темплейт. Через админку вы можете добавить этот html в текстовый виджет. А что не так, добавили и редактируйте текст

Comment: как сделать чтобы этот блок отображался только на первой странице? или нужно другой сайдбар создать?

Comment: Нужно сделать проверку https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page

Comment: Тут нужно уже смотреть, ну или можно новый зарегистрировать с нужными параметрами

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите как регистрируется сайдбар, может вам это поможет решить проблему https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar